# UI5 MessageBox remain transparent

Tags: sapui5

I have a message box that I want to do some extra editing on a line. But once I show it, it remains transparent. Is there something that I'm missing to give it a normal background.

The fragment for the form:

```
     <Label text="UnitPrice"/>
        <Input id='unitpriceid' type="Text" text="{path: 'UnitPrice' }"/>
        <Label text="Quantity"/>
        <Input type="Text" text="{path: 'Quantity' }"/>
    </form:SimpleForm>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

How I call the fragment.

```
handleLineItemPress : function (evt) {
    var context = evt.getSource().getBindingContext();
    var oLayout = sap.ui.xmlfragment("ApproveSESComponent.DO_SES.view.LinePopup", this);
    var oModelTemp = this.getView().getModel().getData();
    // get the view and add the layout as a dependent. Since the layout is being put
    // into an aggregation any possible binding will be 'forwarded' to the layout.
    var oView = this.getView();
    oView.addDependent(oLayout);

    var that = this;
    sap.m.MessageBox.show(oLayout, {
          icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.INFORMATION,
          title: "My message box title",
          styleClass: "sapUiSizeCompact",
          actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES, sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO],
          onClose: function(oAction) { / * do something * / }
      });}
```

Comment: The method show expects a message string, you pass a fragment?!

Comment: It does support a layout sap.m.MessageBox.show(vMessage, mOptions?)

The only mandatory parameter is vMessage. Either a string with the corresponding text or even a layout control could be provided.

Comment: You are right, it accepts controls as well, but I'm not sure if it was intended to pass complete layouts to the message box. I would assume it is rather meant for simple controls, e.g. Text. In complex cases I would prefer using a dedicated dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I change the    styleClass: "sapUiSizeCompact" to soemthing else and then added a background-color to this style. 
Then the box was no longer transperant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sap.m.MessageBox is designed for input other than simple button-based choices. Certainly that's how I read the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MessageBox.html) (and that's how message boxes typically work in other APIs):

> Provides easier methods to create sap.m.Dialog with type sap.m.DialogType.Message, such as standard alerts, confirmation dialogs, or arbitrary message dialogs.

You may be able to shoehorn it into allowing you to add an input field but I don't think that's how it's designed (it looks undocumented to me) and don't be surprised if it breaks in a future release. Rather use sap.m.Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here...

Solution: I used the sap.m.MessageBox in a project based on sap.ui.common elements. Replaced it with sap.ui.common.MessageBox and I had a well working Message Box.